# How to fix my code so it will find the password critera i set

Tags: java

Every time I try to have a user generate a password it will always come back as false, regardless if I type it the standard I set.

I have tried rewriting the check method several times, but with no luck. I tried using ArrayList to come compare.

```
public boolean check(String password) 
{
    if(password.length() < 6 && password.length() > 16) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    Pattern special = Pattern.compile (specialChars);
    Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(password);
    int i = 0;
    boolean hasDigit = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    while(i < password.length() && !hasDigit && !hasLower && !hasUpper) 
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasDigit = true;
        } 
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasLower = true;
        } 
        else if(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasUpper = true;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return hasDigit && hasUpper && hasLower && hasSpecial.find();
}
```

I expect the password to return false if it less than 6 character and more than 16. Also the password must contain 1 numerical digit, one uppercase, one lowercase and one special character

Comment: On a side note: never ever store passwords in String objects! String objects may reside in memory longer than you want and as String is immutable you have no means of overwriting them. Use char[] instead, this way you can use Arrays.fill(...) to delete the password data after usage.

Answer (score 0):

Your while statement is wrong:

```
while(i < password.length() && !hasDigit && !hasLower && !hasUpper)
```

When one of the flags turns to true, the while loop will exit, since it will be turned to false (the ! sign) and the expression will evaluate to false.

To further explain, imagine that the first character of the password is a digit. Then, the flag hasDigit will be turned to true. All other flags are false.

The expression :

```
while(i < password.length() && !hasDigit && !hasLower && !hasUpper)
```

turns to :

```
while(i < password.length() && false && true && true)
```

And the whole expression evaluates to false.

Consider revising your while statement to match the criteria you are looking for.

Comment: I would edit in something about `password.length() < 6 && password.length() > 16` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues with your code

1) The while condition.
To met your criteria, it should be

```
 while(i < password.length() && !(hasDigit && hasLower && hasUpper))
```

This will ensure that even if a single `boolean(hasDigit/hasLower/hasUpper)` value is false, the loop continues till the end of `password` string length

2) The special character String defined in pattern initialization. It should be something like this: `[#$&!]`

Below is the complete code snippet

```
public class Snippet {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
    Snippet snippet = new Snippet();
    System.out.println(snippet.check("Abcd#fg1d#"));
}

public boolean check(String password) 
{
    if(password.length() < 6 && password.length() > 16) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    Pattern special = Pattern.compile ("[#!]");
    Matcher hasSpecial = special.matcher(password);
    int i = 0;
    boolean hasDigit = false;
    boolean hasLower = false;
    boolean hasUpper = false;
    while(i < password.length() && (!hasDigit || !hasLower || !hasUpper)) 
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasDigit = true;
        } 
        else if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasLower = true;
        } 
        else if(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) 
        {
            hasUpper = true;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return hasDigit && hasUpper && hasLower && hasSpecial.find();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the first if is never true. the length cannot be shorter than 6 AND longer than 16. change it to OR

```
if(password.length() < 6 || password.length() > 16)
```

regarding the while loop, remove everything except

```
i < password.length()
```

You always want to iterate all the chars in the password.

Answer (score 0):

You'll never finish looping through all the characters with that while loop also you dont need too use a while loop

```
    public boolean check(String password) {
        if (password.length() < 6 && password.length() > 16) {
            return false;
        }
        boolean hasSpecial = password.matches(specialChars);
        boolean hasDigit = password.matches(".*\\d+.*");
        boolean hasLower = !password.equals(password.toUpperCase());
        boolean hasUpper = !password.equals(password.toLowerCase());
        return hasDigit && hasUpper && hasLower && hasSpecial;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean check(String password) {

        boolean hasDigit, hasLower, hasUpper, hasSpecial;
        hasDigit = hasLower = hasUpper = hasSpecial = false;

        if (password.length() >= 6 && password.length() <= 16) {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < password.length()) {
                if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                    hasDigit=true;
                }
                else if(Character.isLowerCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                    hasLower=true;
                }
                else if(Character.isUpperCase(password.charAt(i))) {
                    hasUpper=true;
                }
                else if(!Character.isLetterOrDigit(password.charAt(i))) {
                    hasSpecial=true;
                }

                if (hasDigit && hasLower && hasUpper && hasSpecial) {
                    return true;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```